# Where and group by clause on Subquery and with Join

Tags: sql-server

I have this table:

```
+------------+-------------------+----------+--------+
| query_name | result            | position | rating |
+------------+-------------------+----------+--------+
| Dog        | Golden Retriever  | 1        | 5      |
| Dog        | German Shepherd   | 2        | 5      |
| Dog        | Mule              | 200      | 1      |
| Cat        | Shirazi           | 5        | 2      |
| Cat        | Siamese           | 3        | 3      |
| Cat        | Sphynx            | 7        | 4      |
+------------+-------------------+----------+--------+
```

And Im asked to find:
query name
Quality = Where quality is the average of the ratio between rating and its position. =

- Dog quality is ((5 / 1) + (5 / 2) + (1 / 200)) / 3 = 2.50
- Cat quality equals ((2 / 5) + (3 / 3) + (4 / 7)) / 3 = 0.66

and the poor_query_percentage.= Poor query percentage is The percentage of all queries with rating less than 3. =
Dog queries poor_ query_percentage is (1 / 3) * 100 = 33.33
Cat queries poor_ query_percentage is (1 / 3) * 100 = 33.33

The expected result is:

```
+------------+---------+-----------------------+
| query_name | quality | poor_query_percentage |
+------------+---------+-----------------------+
| Dog        | 2.50    | 33.33                 |
| Cat        | 0.66    | 33.33                 |
+------------+---------+-----------------------+
```

So far I've been able to do this:

--quality

```
SELECT query_name, 
CAST(AVG(rating/position+.0) AS DECIMAL(4,2)) as quality,
(select COUNT(q.rating)from queries as q join queries as b on q.result = b.result where q.rating < 3 GROUP BY q.query_name )/((select count(rating)+.0  from queries))*100

FROM queries
group by query_name
```

If im not wrong the first part is working, is the subquery that I can't get to work and not sure why.

My problem started when I needed Where > 3 for the division, since I cant use it so it will will affect the other statement as well...

```
select count(rating)
FROM queries
WHERE rating < 3
GROUP BY query_name
```

So I tried to solve it as you can see making that subquery...

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a case when to get the count you need vs the total count:

```sql
select query_name, AVG(rating / (position * 1.0))
, COUNT(CASE WHEN rating < 3 THEN 1 END) / (COUNT(*) * 1.0)
from 
(
    VALUES  (N'Dog', N'Golden Retriever', 1, 5)
    ,   (N'Dog', N'German Shepherd', 2, 5)
    ,   (N'Dog', N'Mule', 200, 1)
    ,   (N'Cat', N'Shirazi', 5, 2)
    ,   (N'Cat', N'Siamese', 3, 3)
    ,   (N'Cat', N'Sphynx', 7, 4)
) t (query_name,result,position,rating)
group by query_name
```

I also changed your query to use average for some simplification.

Comment: Yes it worked! I never thought or saw someone using  Case inside count. Love it, thanks!

Comment: It's called conditional aggregation, and is very useful, it's like a WHERE but without actually removing anything.

Comment: thanks for the name of the topic! Ill google that topic and take notes about it,indeed looks very useful